# Perform a static transformation to outside a views bounds

Tags: android, canvas

A quick question, is it possible for a custom ViewGroup to override

```
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t)
```

and have transformation place the view drawing outside of the viewGroups bounds?

I thought i saw a method relating to toggling clipping in this way but not sure if i have made it up!

At the moment I am increading the padding of the viewGroup as needed and calling `setClipToPadding(false)` so i can draw in the padding region.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, found it!

Just in case anyone else wantes to know, the [android:clipChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3aclipChildren) attribute of ViewGroup is what i want.

I imagine if you go the route of using a custom Animation then you should override the `Animation.willChangeBounds` also.

EDIT: I found that when `clipChildren` does not seem to work then just invalidating the parent can do the trick (say inside a `Runnable` driving a frame animation)

Comment: i had this problem again a year later and found this question - who needs anyone else!